# Proving normality in a factor of a direct product

Tags: group-theory

Let $G= A \times B$ with $N \unlhd A$ and $H \leq G$.

The following is part of proof of Proposition 4.3 appearing in the paper [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002186930800611X)

Suppose that $H$ and $HN$ satisfies the conditions $N_G(H) = N_A( \pi_A(H)) \times N_B(\pi_B(H))$ and $N_G(HN) = N_A(\pi_A(H))N \times N_B(\pi_B(H))$ respectively.

Furthermore, assume that $HN \unlhd G$

> I need to show that $\pi_A(H) \unlhd A$ and  $\pi_B(H) \unlhd B$

From $HN \unlhd G$, we have that $N_G(HN) = G = A\times B = N_A(\pi_A(H))N \times N_B(\pi_B(H))$

For any $b \in B$, we have that $b\in N_B(\pi_B(H))$. Hence $\pi_B(H) \unlhd B$

Using the similar argument, for any $a\in A$, we obtain $a \in N_A(\pi_A(H))N $. I'm not sure how to proceed to show that $\pi_A(H) \unlhd A$

Comment: Just got it now....

Comment: @DonAntonio. Please look at the Proposition for any clarification or if I have missed out any important details

Comment: As it stands, it is simply not true. We could take $N=A$, and $H$ any subgroup of $A$, which of course is not necessarily normal.